# What are the possible values of sub-options for Classify[]?

Tags: options, machine-learning

Specifically, how can I find the possible values of sub-option "KernelType" of option "Method" for Classify? Here's an example:

```
trainingset = 
  ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "TrainingData"];
c = Classify[trainingset, 
  Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", 
    "KernelType" -> "RadialBasisFunction", 
    "MulticlassMethod" -> "OneVersusAll"}]
```

And more generally (although this has been asked previously) I'd like to programmatically enumerate all discrete string values for valid sub-options for any given function.

Comment: Linear, Sigmoid, Polynomial, RadialBasisFunction, Automatic

Comment: Thanks @Rojo! How did you find these?

Comment: With some very manual and ungeneralizeable spelunking. This machine learning package is quite closed

Comment: Why is there no documentation? Seems funny!

Comment: Perhaps because of lack of time, perhaps because they don't feel confident about the functionality not having bugs or being future-proof, who knows. What I don't like is the fact that they try hard to hide the code. Its all Locked

Comment: Is there any way to unlock the symbols?

Comment: Not officially and not that I know of

Comment: How about the options for "MulticlassMethod"?

Answer (score 3):

Sub-options for `Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"` include:

- `Linear`
- `Sigmoid`
- `Polynomial`
- `RadialBasisFunction`
- `Automatic`

In 12.3, there is a help page
ref/method/SupportVectorMachine

[image]